# adding custom float to pre existing wordpress template without damage

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Long story short is. I created this http://jsfiddle.net/paDmg/368/ and I would like to add it to www.avueduesgins.com/new on the right hand side underneath the banner next to latest works.

The reason why I do not use a widget is because I do not the transparent background. I would like if I could replicate the style divs in a 3x3 fashion but they need to be rollovers...

Our php guy is out of town for 2 weeks, and I would like to get this project finished. I have very limited skills in php, but with the right direction I am sure I can achieve my goal, I just need help finding which way to go.

If there is another way to achieve what I am trying to do I would like to take any advice. Thanks and hope someone can help a fellow out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add it as a widget, but then use CSS to remove the background? If that's the only thing preventing you from using a widget, CSS is easier than changing your sidebar template.

#yourwidgetsid {background:none}